# savon2 please show example of query

Tags: ruby, savon

I have a SOAP client, and want to make a query to it with '74326' value. Please help me to build it.

```
<xs:element name="CheckContactor">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="INN" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am trying to achieve this in the following way:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: ENV['SOAP_WSDL'], 
                      basic_auth: [ENV['SOAP_USERNAME'],
                      ENV['SOAP_PASSWORD']])
@soap = client.call(:check_contactor,
                     message: { complex_type: { inn: '1234' } })
```

Please give me any example!

Comment: We need to see what you've tried. Please include source code you've written.

Comment: @theTinMan, I wrote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code was just:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: ENV['SOAP_WSDL'], 
                  basic_auth: [ENV['SOAP_USERNAME'],
                  ENV['SOAP_PASSWORD']])

@soap = client.call(:check_contactor, message: { 'INN' => '1234' })
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving any errors? More information would be good to give  you a good answer. Example:

Wsdl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mag="http://magiccompany.com/supermagic">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mag:example>
         <someStuff>123</someStuff>
         <someAuthStuff xmlns:n2="http://magiccompany.com/specialstuff"
      xsi:type="n2:SpecialLogin">
           <username>abc</username>
           <password>test123</password>
         </someAuthStuff>
      </mag:example>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Ruby:

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'wsdl/magic.wsdl', ssl_verify_mode: :none, ssl_version: :TLSv1)

client.call(:example, message: {
  someStuff: 123,
  someAuthStuff: {
    username: "abc",
    password: "test123"
  }, 
  :attributes! => {
   someAuthStuff: {
     "xsi:type" => "n2:SpecialLogin",
     "xmlns:n2" => "http://magiccompany.com/specialstuff"
   }
 }
})
```

Reference: https://coderwall.com/p/erwfda

Comment: Sergio, will try you example soon

Comment: Sergio, can you write me an example of query for my structure?

Comment: Please provide your complete wsdl file.